# How to translate hashing with 'openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt $data' to node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl, md5, crypt

I am trying to imitate the behaviour of `openssl passwd -1 -salt k7Ko8SgF di6cqUaQBuUOd7WhURXDq04022` in nodejs.

The result of this operation is `$1$k7Ko8SgF$CN8PPKddtp5gONSRp4B56/` and I know the hash is the 4th section after the third '$'.

If I try:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const newsalt = 'k7Ko8SgF'; 
const key = 'di6cqUaQBuUOd7WhURXDq04022';
let sign = crypto.createHash('md5').update(newsalt + key).digest("base64");
console.log(sign);
```

I get `n0cLvfi4LQFpIVbZ94gCIA==`

I am not even sure the digest("base64") is even correct to be honest, as I don't know what exactly does openssl spit out.

I am unable to obtain the same hash string that I get with openssl. I need to get the same hash, as the program with which I am trying to communicate doesn't work unless the hash provided is produced with openssl as specified above.

Maybe someone can point me in the write direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The algorithm is significantly more complex. [Here](https://github.com/Holixus/nano-md5) is a NodeJS library that can be used to reproduce the OpenSSL output (with `md5.crypt('di6cqUaQBuUOd7WhURXDq04022', 'k7Ko8SgF')`).

Comment: Wow! @Topaco thank you very much for that tip! It solved the problem completely! I am really thankful! If you post it as solution I will mark as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Topaco the best way to emulate the behaviour of `openssl passwd -1 -salt yoursalt password` on NodeJS is using the nano-MD5 library found [here](https://github.com/Holixus/nano-md5)
Hope this helps someone else looking into this same problem!